# How to add button in custom EditForm.aspx ribbon?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, ribbon, edit-form, custom-action

I have a task list and in my task list I am using custom a `EditForm.aspx` page instead of default a `EditForm.aspx`.

I want to add a ribbon button in my custom form. Actually we are overriding the default `EditForm.aspx` and in that form I am adding some custom code.

I check my list in SharePoint Designer and the custom ribbon shows there but it is not added to the ribbon of EditForm.

Here is how I implement a button in the ribbon in my code:

```
<CustomAction
  Id="SaveAndContinueForm.EditFormToolbar"
  RegistrationId="150"
  RegistrationType="List"
  Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView"
  Sequence="5"
  Title="Save and New">
<!--<UrlAction Url="/crm/Lists/listname/EditForm.aspx"/>-->
<CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Commit.Controls._children">
      <Button
      Id="SaveAndContinueForm.Toolbar.Ribbon.Button"
      Alt="Save and New"
      Sequence="1"
      Command="Ribbon.EditForm.Custom.Button.SaveAndContinue"
      Image32by32="~site/_layouts/1033/images/SaveAs32.png"
      LabelText="Save and Continue"
      TemplateAlias="o1" />
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>

  <CommandUIHandlers>
    <CommandUIHandler
    Command="Ribbon.EditForm.Custom.Button.SaveAndContinue"
    CommandAction="javascript:javascriptMethodCall('{ListId}','{ItemId}','{SiteUrl}');"
/>
  </CommandUIHandlers>
</CommandUIExtension>
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: try to change the Location Value in the CustomAction tag to "CommandUI.Ribbon.DisplayForm". In the Image32by32 attribute of the Button tag you dont need "~site", i think

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing Maxsize element, try by adding the following code after  section

```
 <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Scaling._children">
      <MaxSize
        Id="Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.MaxSize"
        Sequence="15"
        GroupId="Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Groups.CustomGroup"
        Size="NewGroupInExistingTabOneLarge" />          
    </CommandUIDefinition>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Groups._children">
      <Group Id="Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Groups.CustomGroup"
        Sequence="100" Title="Actions"
        Description="Custom Action Group"
        Template="Ribbon.Templates.CustomTemplate">
        <Controls Id="Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Groups.CustomGroup.Controls">
          <Button
            Id="Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Groups.CustomGroup.Controls.Button"
            Alt="Select Image"
            Sequence="1"
            Image32by32="/_layouts/images/PicturePicker/image_32.png"
            Command="SelectImageCommand"
            LabelText="Select Image"
            TemplateAlias="Button1"
            CommandType="General"/>
        </Controls>
      </Group>
    </CommandUIDefinition>
```

Comment: Thanks @Anuja for your reply, but doesn't works for me as i am using default ribbon not custom one. What i did is just placing custom webpart in the main zone of EditForm.aspx. Can you suggest any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

update you location attribute with

```
Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.EditForm"
```

and add rights attribute in custom action

```
Rights="EditListItems"
```